# Find every K such that arr[i]%K is equal to for each arr[i]

Tags: algorithm, math, greatest-common-divisor, modular-arithmetic

I have an array of M integers. I have to find all possible integers K (given there is at least 1 K)such that:

```
1) K > 1
2) arr[0]%K = arr[1]%K = arr[2]%K = ... = arr[M-1]%K
```

What is the best algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Yes, K should divide all the integers in the array with same remainder @ZX9

Comment: Ok, I edited problem, @ZX9, thank you

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the GCD (greatest common divisor) of all `arr[i] - m (except m)` where `m` is the smallest element in `arr[]`;

Comment: @RBarryYoung That doesn't take into account negative values. Perhaps the smallest *positive* element? (See my answer which takes care of negative values.)

Comment: @ZX9 No, I did mean the smallest number (*not* smallest magnitude).  This does handle negative numbers by making all of the diffs positive or zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First, let's examine the givens.

- Given that *there exists at least one `K`*, we know that, for example, the array `arr` such that `arr[0]=4; arr[1]=6; arr[2]=9`
  is not valid because no modulus gives the same result for each.
- Given that `K` > 1, we know that all values of the array cannot be the same. They are, however, the same `modK` for all `K`.

Keep in mind that `arr[i]%K` (for any i such that `0=<i<M`) does not have to be positive.

### A Proposed Algorithm

*Code has not been tested*

It seems to me as if the simplest way of determining `K` values will be from finding the differences between each value in the array. (I'm going to show examples in Java.) Let's say that `arrDiff` contains the differences of each value such that

```
arrDiff[0] = arr[0]-arr[1];
arrDiff[1] = arr[1] - arr[2];
...
arrDiff[M-1] = arr[M-1] - arr[0];
```

Now, find `G = gcd(arrDiff[0],arrDiff[1],...,arrDiff[M-1]` to find all valid `K`. You can use whatever `gcd` method you wish, which is the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations), in order to iteratively/recursively find 
`G`. You can also ignore negative differences since `gcd` will give you positive results.

`[All of G's factors]>1` (including `G` itself) will be valid `K` values.

### Walking Through It

I'm not going to do a proof (I'll leave that to you), but let's do an example just to be clear.

#### Initialize an example `arr`

```
//Let's do an easy one with M=3
int arr[] = new int[3];
arr[0] = -7;
arr[1] = 9;
arr[2] = 25
```

#### Create the difference array

I'll show a slightly more efficient implementation here (thanks to @RBarryYoung).

```
int min = findSmallestNumber(arr); //Returns min value (may be negative)
//The array size is intended to not include the minimum, assuming we have no duplicates.
int arrDiff[] = new int[arr.length-1];
for(int num : arr){
    if(num==min) continue; 
    arrDiff[num] = arr[num] - min;
}
```

For the example above, this code should give us values of `16,32` in `arrDiff`. Notice that using this method should result in all positive values for gcd calculations in the next step.

#### Calculate `G = gcd`

I'm not going to write a gcd method for you, since there are lots of implementations; I'll assume you have a method `int gcd(int a, int b)`.

```
int g = gcd(arrDiff[0], arrDiff[1]);
for(int i = 2, i < arrDiff.length-1, i++){
    g = gcd(g, arrDiff[i]);
}
//return g;
```

Note that if we only have two values in the array, no `gcd` usage is necessary--just use the single difference.

#### Checking the Example

For our example, you can easily find that the gcd(-16,-16,32)=gcd(16,16,32)=16. Thus 16 and all of its factors >1 should be answers. Let's check 16 at least. Note that the below "=" should really be a congruence symbol (three bars not two).

> -7mod16 = 9mod16
>
> 9mod16 = 9mod16
>
> 25mod16 = 9mod16

You can check that this also works for factors `2,4,8`. (For all of these factors, you should get `1mod8 => 1mod4 => 1mod2`.)

#### Wrap-up

If you have to find the factors in code, you may be interested in one of the various [factoring algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Factoring_algorithms) to find all factors of `G` greater than 1. Picking the most optimized may depend on your data.

Thus, it's really a combination of algorithms which you may need. There may be slightly faster ways of doing what I showed you above, but the basic algorithm should be approachable now.

Comment: You can normalize this more by changing the differencing from `diff[i] = arr[i] - arr[i+1]` to `diff[i] = arr[i] - m`, (removing any zeroes) where `m` is the least element of `arr[]`.  This will make all the diffs positive and eliminates the need to handle the weirdness that many language's mod functions have with negative numbers.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Ahh, you are correct. My apologies and thank you. Updating the question.

Comment: @sanapalamohanarao Glad to hear it! Thanks for a good question. ;)

Comment: @ZX9, a small problem is there, if n==2, we have only one element in difference array (diff[0]). We cannot find GCD(diff[0],diff[1]). in that situation. I just used diff[0] as GCD. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int GCD(int a, int b) {
    while(a!=b) {
        if(a>b) a-=b; else b-=a;
    }
    return a;
}
int main()
{
   int n; scanf("%d",&n);
   int a[n],i,j;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
   }
   //finding minimum
  int min=a[0]; for(i=0;i<n;i++) if(min>a[i]) min=a[i];

  //finding differences and storing except minimum
  int diff[n-1]; for(i=0,j=0;i<n;i++) if(a[i]!=min) diff[j++]=a[i]-min;

  // if n is 2, we have only diff[1], otherwise we can follow algo
  int g=(n==2)?diff[0]:GCD(diff[0],diff[1]); for(i=2;i<n-1;i++) g=GCD(g,diff[i]);

  //finding divisors of the final gcd.
  for(i=2;i<=g;i++) if(g%i==0)printf("%d ",i);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to the problem

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void printEqualModNumbers (int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    sort(arr, arr + n);  
    int d = arr[n-1] - arr[0]; 

    vector <int> v; 
    for (int i=2; i*i<=d; i++) 
    { 
        if (d%i == 0) 
        { 
            v.push_back(i); 
            if (i != d/i) 
                v.push_back(d/i); 
        } 
    } 
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) 
    { 
        int temp = arr[0]%v[i]; 

        int j; 
        for (j=1; j<n; j++) 
            if (arr[j] % v[i] != temp) 
                break; 

        if (j == n) 
            cout << v[i] <<" "; 
    } 
} 

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    printEqualModNumbers(arr, n);
}
```